# How do I defer loading a component until my signalr service is initialized?

Tags: asynchronous, angular, typescript, signalr

I have the following types:
DataService - Gets data from the server using signalr hub.
AppComponent - which is the entry point for my main application

The data service constructor is as follows.

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
    var hub = $.connection.spwHub;
    hub.client.loadEmployees = this.loadEmployees;
    $.connection.hub.start().done(() => {
         ...
    });
}
```

My AppComponent is as follows:

```
constructor(service: DataService) {    
    this.company = service.getCompany();
    service.getEmployees().then(employees => this.employees = employees);
    this.departments = service.getDepartments();
}
```

I get the following error of course because the hub async call has not returned before the hub connection is made.

EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: SignalR: Connection has not been fully initialized. Use .start().done() or .start().fail() to run logic after the connection has started.

What is the best way to deal with this issue in AngularJs2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the APP_INITIALIZER hook to perform logic, get something prepped, whatever, that you need before the rest of the application runs.

In your **app.module.ts** (or whatever your main module is):

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule }      from "@angular/core";
export function init_app(employeeService: EmployeeService) {
    return () => employeeService.getEmployees();
}

@NgModule({
    <...>
    providers: [EmployeeService, {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: init_app,
        deps: [ EmployeeService ],
        multi: true
    }]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The service is returning a Promise which will be automatically handled:

```
getEmployees() {
    return <...function stuff ...>
            .toPromise();
}
```

And here's the github issue where this is documented (no doc on the angular.io site yet): https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9047

Comment: I am still unsure. I mean I want a random function to handle the signalr. I could just  $.connection.hub.start().done(() => { ... }); But, this defeats the purpose. I don't want to load the data from outside my AppComponent. I don't only need to run some code initially, I also have to have that code return before app component loads.

Answer (score 0):

After searching and finding nothing I gave the idea that components that don't need to be loaded should probably be deferred by default. This means that the answer is a no-brainer.

```
// start.component.ts
constructor() {
    // Start the connection
    var hub = $.connection.spwHub;
    $.connection.hub.start().done(() => {
         // This loads the next component and runs the constructor
         this.initialized = true;
    });
}

// start.component.html
<div *ngIf="initialized">
    <main-component></main-component>
<div>

// This type is lazy loaded as soon as the initialized equals true.
// main.component.ts
constructor(employeeService: EmployeeService) {
    // Finally, load the needed data.
    this.employees = employeeService.getEmployees();
}
```